# Failed signature verification

Tags: verification

I have followed the instructions for verifying the Tor exe on Windows using GnuPG and command prompt (here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/verifying-signatures.html.en) but haven't been able to get an output. I have successfully imported the key and checked the fingerprint but when I paste the following nothing at all happens as an output:

```
"D:\Installed Applications\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --verify
  C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\torbrowser-install-6.5.1_en-US.exe.asc
  C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\torbrowser-install-6.5.1_en-US.exe
```

What's wrong? Is it a problem that I have GnuPG installed on a different drive?

Comment: This command worked for me. gpg --homedir "$HOME/.local/share/torbrowser/gnupg_homedir/" --refresh-keys --keyserver pgp.mit.edu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description behind the link you provided is a bit unclear.

The command needs to look like this (all on the same line):

```
"D:\Installed Applications\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe" --verify C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\torbrowser-install-6.5.1_en-US.exe.asc C:\Users\MyUsername\Desktop\torbrowser-install-6.5.1_en-US.exe
```

Comment: Opened a ticket to have description improved [#21808](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21808)

Comment: Your advice worked and it's now giving an output. Thank you. Yes, the description isn't very transparent if you haven't done it before. Out of  interest, do the line indentations on the description symbolise that it should be on one line? Is it a space saving convention when describing commands?

Comment: Also, I think the description of GnuPG and the gpg.exe path are out of date. I installed the latest version and the path is "...\Gnu\GnuPg\pub\gpg.exe" rather than "...\Gnu\GnuPg\gpg.exe". The GnuPG folder only contains gpg2.exe. Is that an out of date path?

Comment: It still does not work at my end. I typed the in the following: "C:\Program Files\GnuPG\bin\gpg.exe" --verify C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\torbrowser-install-win64-8.0.9_de.exe.asc C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\torbrowser-install-win64-8.0.9_de.exe In the picture below you can see what it spews out. Please help!
Thanks for your help! [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGR44.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGR44.jpg)
Note: -I have another version of tor (German and other release). But I took care of that.
-The directory of GnuPG for the .exe file has changed. I actualized that